# Symfony2 form fails to detect if entity or uploaded file was submited

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a Form `PostType` that creates an Entity called `Post` this form has an embedded sub form `PhotoType` for the entity `Photo`.

On Edit of `Post` I exchange the `PhotoType` Form for an `ImagePreviewType` Form to show a small Preview of the `Photo` and disallow any changes of the `Photo`.

This works fine, but the Problem is, when I prefill the `PostType` form to create a `Post` that is similar to an old `Post`. The form renders fine and I see the `Photo` in the `ImagePreviewType` but on submit the `$builder->getData()` data is empty and I'm unable to select `ImagePreviewType` again so the from fallsback to `PhotoType` and expects an uploaded file but receives the entity and throws an error.

I hope you can understand my problem, here is my source with a comment, where it fails:

`PostType`:

```
<?php

namespace Socialised\FbPostingBundle\Form;

use Socialised\FbPostingBundle\Entity\Post;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Url;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Socialised\FbPostingBundle\Form\Type\ImagePreviewType;
use Socialised\FbPostingBundle\Form\Type\VideoPreviewType;

class PostType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {


        $builder
            ->add('message', 'textarea', array(
                'required' => false,
                'label'    => 'form.label.message',
                'attr' => array('class' => 'variable photo text link video'),
            ))
            ->add('link', 'url', array(
                    'required' => false,
                    'label' => 'form.helptext.link.url',
                    'constraints' =>  new Url(),
                    'attr' => array('class' => 'variable link'),
                )
            )

        if ($builder->getData()->getPhoto() != null){  // <- This is where it fails
            /*               
                On submit of a new Entity $builder->getData() is empty, even thought data valid is submit.
                I'm unable to detect if an image was uploaded or the reference to an `Photo` was send. So the wrong Form is selected.
            */           
            $builder->add('photo', new ImagePreviewType(), array(
                'label'    => 'form.label.photo',
                'horizontal_input_wrapper_class' => 'variable photo col-lg-8',
                'translation_domain' => 'SocialisedFbPostingBundle',
            ));
        }else{            
            $builder->add('photo', new PhotoType(), array(
                'required' => false,
                'label'    => 'form.label.photo',
                'horizontal_input_wrapper_class' => 'variable photo col-lg-8',
                'translation_domain' => 'SocialisedFbPostingBundle',
            ))
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Socialised\FbPostingBundle\Entity\Post',
            'translation_domain' => 'SocialisedFbPostingBundle',
            'show_legend' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-horizontal'
            ),
            'securityContext' => false
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'socialised_fbpostingbundle_post';
    }
}
```

`PhotoType`:

```
<?php
namespace Socialised\FbPostingBundle\Form;

use Socialised\FbPostingBundle\Entity\Post;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Image;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File;

class PhotoType  extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('file', 'file', array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => false,
                    'constraints' => array(new Image(array(
                            'minWidth' => 200,
                            'minHeight' => 200,
                        )),
                        new File(array(
                            'maxSize' => '4096k',
                        ))
                    ),
                )
            )
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Socialised\FbPostingBundle\Entity\Photo',
            'translation_domain' => 'SocialisedFbPostingBundle',
            'show_legend' => false,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'socialised_fbpostingbundle_photo';
    }
}
```

`ImagePreviewType`:

```
<?php
namespace Socialised\FbPostingBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Socialised\FbPostingBundle\Form\PhotoType;

class ImagePreviewType extends AbstractType
{
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            //'class' => 'SocialisedFbPostingBundle:Photo',
            'data_class' => 'Socialised\FbPostingBundle\Entity\Photo',
            'property' => 'id',
            'by_reference' => false,
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'text';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'imagepreview';
    }
}
```

SOLUTION:

Adding this code to the `PostType` form seem to do the trick.

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    if(is_numeric($data['photo'])){
        $form->add('photo', new ImagePreviewType(), array(
            'label'    => 'form.label.photo',
            'horizontal_input_wrapper_class' => 'variable photo link offer col-lg-8',
            'translation_domain' => 'SocialisedFbPostingBundle',
        ));
    }      

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to use POST_SET_DATA form event?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html

Comment: I think i found solution with your help, i update the question and added the solution i came up with, it seems to work fine right now.